How to Separate Suitelet Script into Custom Module and XML Template in NetSuite?
I have developed a Suitelet script in NetSuite to generate an XML file, and I would like to restructure it into three parts:
A Custom Module that handles the logic for generating XML.
An XML Template for the file structure.
The Suitelet Script that interacts with the custom module and generates the response.
Here's what I have so far:
//Custom Module
var TEMPLATE_FILE_ID = "36530";

define(["N/file", "N/render", "N/record", "N/search", "SuiteScripts/pts_helper1"],
    function (file, render, record, search, util) {

        function generateXml() {
            var invoiceId = 1057613;
            var invoiceRecord = record.load({
                type: 'invoice',
                id: invoiceId
            });

            var xmlTemplateFile = file.load({
                id: TEMPLATE_FILE_ID
            });
        
            const customData = {
                invoiceId: invoiceId
            };

            // Additional logic to populate XML data

        }

        return {
            generateXml: generateXml
        }
    });


//XML Template
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<INVOICE_ID>${customData.invoiceId}</INVOICE_ID>
</xml>


//Suitelet Script
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.1
 *@NScriptType Suitelet
 */
define(["SuiteScripts/mp_ptc_module"], function(customXML) {

    function onRequest(context) {
        try {
            var recId = 1057613;
            var xmlFile = customXML.generateXml(recId);
            context.response.writeFile({ file: xmlFile, isInLine: true });
        } catch (e) {
            log.error("map:error", e);
        }
    }

    return {
        onRequest: onRequest
     }
});


You can convert into modular format as below. There will be 2 modules i.e. a suitelet module and a XML generator. The Template is stored in a file.
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NModuleScope Public
 */
define(['N/file', 'N/render', 'N/record', 'N/search', 'SuiteScripts/pts_helper1'], function(file, render, record, search, util) {

    const TEMPLATE_FILE_ID = "36530";

    /**
     * Generate XML for a given invoice ID
     * @param {number} invoiceId - The ID of the invoice
     * @returns {file.File} - The generated XML file
     */
    function generateXml(invoiceId) {
        var invoiceRecord = record.load({
            type: 'invoice',
            id: invoiceId
        });

        var xmlTemplateFile = file.load({
            id: TEMPLATE_FILE_ID
        });

        const customData = {
            invoiceId: invoiceId
        };

        // Render the XML template with custom data
        var renderer = render.create();
        renderer.templateContent = xmlTemplateFile.getContents();
        renderer.addCustomDataSource({
            format: render.DataSource.OBJECT,
            alias: 'customData',
            data: customData
        });

        var xmlContent = renderer.renderAsString();
        var xmlFile = file.create({
            name: 'invoice_' + invoiceId + '.xml',
            fileType: file.Type.XMLDOC,
            contents: xmlContent,
            folder: -15 // Replace with your folder ID
        });

        return xmlFile;
    }

    return {
        generateXml: generateXml
    };
});

The above is the XML generator and below is suitelet
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.1
 * @NScriptType Suitelet
 */
define(['SuiteScripts/xmlGenerator'], function(xmlGenerator) {

    function onRequest(context) {
        try {
            var recId = 1057613; // Replace with dynamic ID if needed
            var xmlFile = xmlGenerator.generateXml(recId);
            context.response.writeFile({ file: xmlFile, isInline: true });
        } catch (e) {
            log.error("map:error", e);
        }
    }

    return {
        onRequest: onRequest
    };
});

